# is there any way to download Deseq1 package in R?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to load some RData files with the function `load`, but I get this message:

```
Warning: namespace ‘DESeq’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘cds3’
Loading required package: DESeq
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘DESeq’
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘DESeq’
```

Which means that this file can only be opened if I have the old DEseq package installed. I know it's an old package, but I have looked everywhere and searched the bioconductor guide for this package, and tried this code:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("DESeq")
```

and got this error

```
Error: With R version 3.5 or greater, install Bioconductor packages using BiocManager; see https://bioconductor.org/install
```

I already have DEseq2 but I need the first DEseq. I really need to load those files, what can I do ?

Comment: Anyone? is it an impossible task ?

Comment: DESeq was removed from Bioconductor in release 3.13 (May 20, 2021) but you can still try a manual install. The dependencies might be challenging though. I'd suggest doing that in a clean environment, e.g. in a virtual machine, esp since you also have DESeq2 installed.